# how to debug sbt project in eclipse

Tags: scala, sbt

i have a `sbt` project and i want to debug it in `Eclipse`

i have not found anything about debugging in `sbt` documentation

i have found this command `sbt-debug 5005` but it is not working it  says

> sbt-debug: command not found

i have read on blogs that we can do it using third party library but i want to debug my project with sbt

how can i debug my sbt project in eclipse?

please help me

Answer (score 2):

Add the following in `Build.scala`

```
javaOptions in (Test) += "-Xdebug"
javaOptions in (Test) += "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005"
```

Some other useful links to help you -

[sbt and eclipse](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/sbt_0_12_and_Eclipse_Indigo)

[scala-eclipse-sbt-and-debugging](https://zikaprog.wordpress.com/2010/04/19/scala-eclipse-sbt-and-debugging/)

[using-eclipse-and-sbt-in-scala](http://ted-gao.blogspot.fr/2013/02/using-eclipse-and-sbt-in-scala.html)

[Finally, sbt12 and eclipse debug - how to!?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/eIFWKIp9E34)